# responseBody.string() throw timeout issue suddenly

Tags: okhttp

We have such below a class that somewhere is calling returnString but very suddenly get timeout exception in production, but actually the server has returned the success status and data.
Looks something like a buffer is blocked since every time it starts throwing timeout unitl I restart the application. And immediately it becomes healthy.
We have several nodes for this application in production, but very sudden only one node gets this exception and doesn't have any regulation.
Is there any improper usage of the OkHttpClient (or configuration) or is there any potential defect for it? Thanks!

OkHttpClient bean is constructed like:

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(okHttpClientTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(okHttpClientTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).connectTimeout(okHttpClientTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
```

okHttpClientTimeout is coming from env and by default 10.

```
public class ClientHelper {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE_JSON = "application/json";
    private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JSON = MediaType.parse(CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);

    public enum METHOD {
        GET,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE,
        HEAD;
    }

    @Autowired
    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

    public Response returnResponse(METHOD method, String url, String authorization, Map<String, String> requestHeader, String requestBody) {
        String onetimeId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        logger.info("[{}]ClientHelper.Client-Start>>>", onetimeId);
        logger.info("[{}]ClientHelper.url: {} {}", onetimeId, method, url);
        logger.info("[{}]ClientHelper.requestBody: {} ", onetimeId, Optional.ofNullable(requestBody));
        logger.info("[{}]ClientHelper.authorization: {}", onetimeId, authorization);
        try {
            Response response = okHttpClient
                    .newCall(new Request.Builder().url(url)
                            .method(method.toString(),
                                    METHOD.GET.equals(method) || METHOD.HEAD.equals(method) ? null
                                            : RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JSON, Optional.ofNullable(requestBody).orElse("")))
                            .headers(Headers.of(Optional.ofNullable(requestHeader).orElseGet(() -> buildDefaultHead(authorization))))
                            .addHeader(LogContext.HTTP_HEADER_CORRELATION_ID, LogContext.getCorrelationId())
                            .build())
                    .execute();
            logger.info("[{}]ClientHelper.response-status: {}", onetimeId, response.code());
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ...RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            logger.info("[{}]...", onetimeId);
        }
    }

    public String returnBody(METHOD method, String url, String authorization, Map<String, String> requestHeader, String requestBody) {
        try (Response response = returnResponse(method, url, authorization, requestHeader, requestBody)) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                return getResponseBody(response, true);
            }
            throw new ...HttpResponseException("response failed. status:" + response.code() + " url:" + method.toString() + " " + url
                    + " response body: " + getResponseBody(response, false), response.code());
        }
    }

    public String returnString(METHOD method, String url, String authorization, Map<String, String> requestHeader, String requestBody) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(returnBody(method, url, authorization, requestHeader, requestBody))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ...RuntimeException("ClientHelper returnString() method result is null"));
    }

    private String getResponseBody(Response response, boolean isThrow) {
        try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
            return responseBody.string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (isThrow) {
                throw new ...RuntimeException(e);
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, String> buildDefaultHead(String authorization) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Continuous and large performance testing for this code but haven't reproduced.
Upgraded the okhttp.version from 3.9.1 to 4.11.0, still got the same issue suddenly.